# Character limit on Bundle-Classpath in OSGi bundle manifest?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

Using Apache Felix, I have an OSGi component I've authored that wraps some middleware my company uses.  Currently it depends on a good number of external libraries, and I appear to have run into a limit on the Bundle-classpath: parameter length.  I've had to rename libraries such as commons-collections.jar to ccoll.jar.

I'm curious if anyone has any advice on working around this limitation?

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,lib/log4j.jar,lib/cvfs.jar,lib/backport.jar,lib/cbeanutils.jar,lib/ccodec.jar,lib/ccoll.jar,lib/chttp.jar,lib/cjxpath.jar,lib/clang.jar,[libs redacted],lib/saaj-api.jar,lib/saaj-impl.jar,lib/Schemas.jar,lib/xbean.jar,lib/clog.jar,lib/dom4j.jar,lib/xml-apis.jar,lib/xerces.jar,lib/xalan.jar,lib/jaxp-ri.jar,lib/japi.jar,lib/mail.jar
```

I suppose I could get more characters by leaving off the lib/ bits, but I'm curious if this is a bug, a defined limitation, or just simply idiocy on my part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manifest line lengths are limited to 72 bytes as stated in http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html. After that you will have to split the line and start a new one beginning with a space character. In this case:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,lib/log4j.jar,lib/cvfs.jar,lib/backport.jar,lib/cbea
 nutils.jar,lib/ccodec.jar,lib/ccoll.jar,lib/chttp.jar,lib/cjxpath.jar,l
 ib/clang.jar,[libs redacted],lib/saaj-api.jar,lib/saaj-impl.jar,lib/Sch
 emas.jar,lib/xbean.jar,lib/clog.jar,lib/dom4j.jar,lib/xml-apis.jar,lib/
 xerces.jar,lib/xalan.jar,lib/jaxp-ri.jar,lib/japi.jar,lib/mail.jar
```

Alternatively you could use a tool like BND that does things like this (and more) for you automatically.

Comment: Note that when he says 'bytes' he really means bytes, not characters. So when you store your file as Unicode UTF-8 and use non-ASCII characters, it becomes completely insane trying to figure out whether some text actually fits on the line. Why MANIFEST.MF has this weird limitation is beyond me.

Answer (score 4):

There is, as [Moritz says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338876/character-limit-on-bundle-classpath-in-osgi-bundle-manifest/3338941#3338941), a [72-byte limit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Name-Value%20pairs%20and%20Sections) per line.

The Java [jar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) package includes code for writing manifests:

```
Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
attributes.put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
attributes
    .putValue(
        "Bundle-Classpath",
        "<snip>");
manifest.write(System.out);
```

*Note: `Manifest-Version` is mandatory.*

This produces the output:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Classpath: .,lib/log4j.jar,lib/cvfs.jar,lib/backport.jar,lib/cb
 eanutils.jar,lib/ccodec.jar,lib/ccoll.jar,lib/chttp.jar,lib/cjxpath.j
 ar,lib/clang.jar,[libsredacted],lib/saaj-api.jar,lib/saaj-impl.jar,li
 b/Schemas.jar,lib/xbean.jar,lib/clog.jar,lib/dom4j.jar,lib/xml-apis.j
 ar,lib/xerces.jar,lib/xalan.jar,lib/jaxp-ri.jar,lib/japi.jar,lib/mail
 .jar
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, consider packaging third-party libraries in their own bundles, some are even osgi-ready.

Comment: An example perhaps?  I presume you can have a bundle without an Activator?

Comment: Yes, Activator classes are optional. I was referring to f.e. commons-beanutils, the JAR of which is a ready-made bundle, as the proper headers are already set in the MANIFEST.MF.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/commons/CommonsOsgi for Apache-Commons OSGi ready libraries. Otherwise look at http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/ if they bundled your 3rd party library already.

Install these bundles independent and do not embed them in your bundle.

Answer (score 1):

First, never directly edit `MANIFEST.MF`. Edit it in a standard text file, for example `mymanifest.txt`, then pass to the `jar` command as follows:

```
jar cfm output.jar mymanifest.txt <other files>
```

The `jar` tool will then insert the line-wraps as necessary.

**Better answer**: use the [Bnd](http://www.aQute.biz/Code/Bnd) tool by Peter Kriens to generate your manifest.

Also as other commenters have pointed out, it is much better to use these libraries as OSGi bundles. Sticking all of your dependencies into one bundle is kind of missing the point of OSGi.